# Development Pod files disappears after running pod install?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, cocoapods

Currently I am creating custom CocoaPod with dependencies ,
I specified dependencies in podspec file following guides of CocoaPods [Guides](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/using-pod-lib-create.html)
Development Pod Classes code disappears after running Pod install but it exists in the finder
when I drag it to the project and add it to the project and run pod lib lint command
I get this error

> [iOS] The `source_files` pattern did not match any file.

tried all solutions for this error on the internet but nothing works!!

Comment: What is the specified for source_files in the podspec? And where are those files relative to the repo root?

Comment: I added s.source_files = 'MyPodName/Classes/**/*' and created Group called classes in Development pod folder then put my source code in it ? @PaulBeusterien

Answer (score 0):

I found what was the issue, Classes folder not appearing in Xcode but it exists in the file system so I was creating Another Classes Folder which will be in another place so the podspec file was unable to find the source files show Development pod folder in finder, then copy your files to classes folder and drag classes folder to you Xcode project to edit the code.